# Google Chrome Ignoring too frequent calls to print()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript print blocked by Chrome, Workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401454/javascript-print-blocked-by-chrome-workaround)

When I make 2 or more `print()` method calls in Google Chrome, the browser prevents the `print()` function in the latest version of Chrome.

This is the Error that I get in the console:

> Ignoring too frequent calls to print().